# How to detect neighbours of a MeshRegion?

Tags: mesh

For a given triangle meshRegion(examplary) `\[CapitalDelta]reg`

```
\[CapitalDelta]reg =DiscretizeRegion[Triangle [], MaxCellMeasure -> 1/10]
```

[image]

I need to know/detect the indexes of neighbouring elements and their common side.
I know the command `MeshCells`.

How to solve this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: You might also want to look into `MeshConnectivityGraph[Δreg, 2]`.

Comment: @flinty Thank you, today I learn a lot of new things

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My first attempt:

```
\[CapitalDelta]reg = 
 DiscretizeRegion[Triangle[], MaxCellMeasure -> 1/10]
polys = MeshPrimitives[\[CapitalDelta]reg, 2]
mcells = MeshCells[\[CapitalDelta]reg, 2]
amc1 = AdjacentMeshCells[\[CapitalDelta]reg, #, 1] & /@ mcells
amc2 = AdjacentMeshCells[\[CapitalDelta]reg, #, 2] & /@ mcells
Manipulate[
 Show[
  HighlightMesh[\[CapitalDelta]reg, amc2[[i]]]
  , Graphics[{AbsolutePointSize[10], Red, 
    Point@RegionCentroid[polys[[i]]]
    }]
  ]
 , {i, 1, Length@mcells, 1}
 ]
```

[image]

You can also see the lines being highlighted by using `amc1` instead of `amc2` above. `polys` is just for centroid calculation.

Comment: Perfect solution, thank you . I didn't know `AdjacentMeshCells[]`

Comment: `AnnotationValue[{\[CapitalDelta]reg, 2}, MeshCellCentroid]` and `RegionCentroid /@ polys` give the same result, so the above solution can be made shorter (something I just discovered).  Try: `Names["*MeshCell*"]`. Thanks for the accept.

Comment: You're welcome. My goal is to model 2D finite volume method(didn't find info on stackexchange), therefore I need this elementwise knowledge of elements and adjacent sides. Thanks again.